# Using .NET objects in XMLSpy Script Editor

Tags: javascript, .net, xmlspy

I'm trying to import a Guid object into my XMLSpy script editor, as described in the manual [CLR.Create](https://www.altova.com/manual/XMLSpy/spyprofessional/scr_cmd_clr_create.html). This is necessary in order to use the generated guid in an xml document, but before that it must be converted to a string.
There is a code

```
var objGuid = CLR.Create("System.Guid");
var guid = objGuid.NewGuid();
confirm(guid);
```

that generates a guid and can display it in a conform-form, but when I try to insert an "guid" with the "ReplaceText" command
`tv.ReplaceText(416, 452, guid);`
a type mismatch error appears
[tmError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFRdj.jpg)
At the same time: an attempt to convert the variable "guid" to a string (guid.toString or guid.ToString()) ends with the error "guid.toString is null or is not an object". Type of "guid" is unknown
[nullError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oegt0.jpg)
The "objGuid" object is converted to a string, but such a guid consists entirely of zeros. Type of "objGuid" is object
[zeroGuid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLNVv.jpg)

Is there any way that will allow me to convert this object to a string correctly?

Thanks!

I tried using a different method [CLR.Static](https://www.altova.com/manual/XMLSpy/spyprofessional/scr_cmd_clr_static.html), but the result is the same.